# Update state after change coming from outside JS functionality into input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and want to do following: I have a react component with input element. The value of input element is controlled by JS functionality that comes from webpack bundle. The value of input element is always changing after user interacts with a map. I need to pass this value to the react component state, and am struggling with it. Can you please help?
This is my code:

```
class MyReactComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat:"",
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <input 
                type="hidden"
                id="lat"
                name="lat"
                disabled 
                onChange={e => this.setState({ lat: e.target.value})}
             />
    )
```

The imported value of input element I can see in the console within .html code, but it does not get transported to the state. Can you please help?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it's possible that events triggered by code do not trigger the `onChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.somevar as a global variable and then use it in the react component. It is the easiest way but I don't think this is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation while working on a project few weeks ago. Changes specified in the onChange event handler only happen manually i.e when onChange event is fired. Even if the value changes programmatically the event does not get fired. If you want to control the state of the component when the value changes, one thing you can do is to pass the new value as props to the component and set the state using that props. This can be done using componentWillReceiveProps or static getDerivedStateFromProps along with componentDidUpdate method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am not following this part ,,one thing you can do is to pass the new value as props to the componenet and set the state using that props,,. In my component I dont get any props from parent element, it is the component functioning on its own. So how can I pass the new value as props to the component? Or am I missing something here? :D